# Node.js restify on Windows

Tags: windows, rest, node.js, windows-7

I want to start developing a REST API with Node.js. My development environment is a Windows 7 machine.

I read that the restify is a good choice for start a REST API, but this module depends from dtrace-provider, and dtrace-provider is not compatible with Windows.

How can I compile this module on windows? There is another way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just use [express-resources](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource)

Comment: +1 for documenting, how people end up choosing node modules. If it doesn't work right away, you try some other ones until you get a fit.

Answer (score 4):

This issue was resolved (https://github.com/mcavage/node-restify/issues/100),
and the DTrace dependency is optional.

It worked for me only on npm 1.1.5, so you might need to update  (`npm update npm@1.1.5 -g` running as administrator).