# Could not install restify

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to install [restify](http://mcavage.github.com/node-restify/) using npm in my windows machine.
    Getting an error and could not install it.

Error I got when looking at the log file

```
info dtrace-provider@0.2.8 Failed to exec install script
```

and all files getting rolled back.

I want to write Restfull web APIs using node.js. Please help me out with this issue.

Note: Find one solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471185/node-js-restify-on-windows), I have installed the current version of node.js with builtin support for npm, and still getting the error. Please help me

Comment: @AlexGad +1 for AlexGad. Implementing some basic some middlewares for a restful api in very trivial with express.js.

Comment: I've been trying to manually install restify downloading the zip and removing any dtrace and bunyan deendencies but I couldn't. It's a shame because restify seems pretty good for building rest services...  SHAME ON YOU DTRACE

Answer (score -1):

You can try express instead restify. It is good. It is simiar to restify.